# H2 database migration from 1.4.192 to 2.1.210

Tags: h2, h2db

I have migrated my h2db.mv.db from 1.4.192 to 2.1.210. All works well application started with the new version of h2(smoothly) but suddenly what I see in my application that h2 database have dropped some tables on its own(runtime). I am not sure why it is happening, but below are some tables which were there before the migration and dropped randomly. Not sure why it is happening

```
create table if not exists alerting_criteria_violations(id identity, timestamp bigint not null, meta " + H2Schema.BINARY_COLUMN_64K, alerting_incident_id bigint not null, foreign key(alerting_incident_id) references alerting_incidents(id) on delete cascade);

create table if not exists config(data " + H2Schema.BINARY_COLUMN_64K + ");


create table if not exists user_alert_messengers(id bigint, user_id bigint, data " + H2Schema.BINARY_COLUMN_64K + ",foreign key (user_id) references users(id) on delete cascade);

create table if not exists user_alert_services(id bigint, user_id bigint, data " + H2Schema.BINARY_COLUMN_64K + ", foreign key (user_id) references users(id) on delete cascade);

create table if not exists user_permissions(user_id bigint, group_id bigint, server_id bigint, permissions smallint,
foreign key (user_id) references users(id) on delete cascade, 
foreign key (group_id) references informix_server_groups(id) on delete cascade, foreign key (server_id) references informix_servers(id) on delete cascade);



H2Schema.BINARY_COLUMN_64K = binary(65536)
```

Earlier my jdbc URL have trace level 4 but now I have changed it to 3 to see the debug logs.

Trace logs for h2db as below

```
2022-06-23 08:43:23 database: disconnecting session #3
2022-06-23 08:43:23 database: closing /Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data/Projects/informixhq-server/server/h2db
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 2 shared read unlock SYS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 shared read unlock SYS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 database: closed
2022-06-23 08:43:23 database: disconnected session #3
2022-06-23 08:43:23 database: opening /Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data/Projects/informixhq-server/server/h2db (build 210)
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive requesting for SYS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive added for SYS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive requesting for INFORMIX_SERVER_GROUPS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive added for INFORMIX_SERVER_GROUPS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive requesting for SYSTEM_REPORTS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive added for SYSTEM_REPORTS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive requesting for ALERTING_INCIDENTS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive added for ALERTING_INCIDENTS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive requesting for USERS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive added for USERS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive requesting for SENSOR_TYPES 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive added for SENSOR_TYPES 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive requesting for ALERTING_CRITERIA_VIOLATIONS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive added for ALERTING_CRITERIA_VIOLATIONS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive requesting for USER_PERMISSIONS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive added for USER_PERMISSIONS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive requesting for USER_ALERT_MESSENGERS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive added for USER_ALERT_MESSENGERS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive requesting for DASHBOARDS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive added for DASHBOARDS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive requesting for USER_ALERT_SERVICES 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive added for USER_ALERT_SERVICES 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive requesting for INFORMIX_SERVERS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive added for INFORMIX_SERVERS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive unlock SYS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive unlock INFORMIX_SERVER_GROUPS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive unlock SYSTEM_REPORTS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive unlock ALERTING_INCIDENTS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive unlock USERS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive unlock SENSOR_TYPES 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive unlock ALERTING_CRITERIA_VIOLATIONS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive unlock USER_PERMISSIONS 
**2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive unlock USER_ALERT_MESSENGERS** 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive unlock DASHBOARDS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive unlock USER_ALERT_SERVICES 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 exclusive unlock INFORMIX_SERVERS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 database: opened /Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data/Projects/informixhq-server/server/h2db
2022-06-23 08:43:23 database: connecting session #3 to /Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data/Projects/informixhq-server/server/h2db
2022-06-23 08:43:23 jdbc[3]: 
/*SQL */SET TRACE_LEVEL_FILE 3;
2022-06-23 08:43:23 jdbc[3]: 
/**/Connection conn2679 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:file:./h2db;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=3", "", "");
2022-06-23 08:43:23 jdbc[3]: 
/**/PreparedStatement prep947 = conn2679.prepareStatement("update informix_servers set alias = ?, hostname = ?, service_name = ?, port = ?, monitor_user = ?, monitor_password = ?, admin_user = ?, admin_password = ?, group_id = ?, profile = ?, alerts = ?, properties = ?, agent_config = ?, password_secret_Key = ?, server_type = ? where id = 11");
2022-06-23 08:43:23 jdbc[3]: Table      :     potential plan item cost 10,390 index PUBLIC.INFORMIX_SERVERS.tableScan
2022-06-23 08:43:23 jdbc[3]: Table      :     potential plan item cost 230 index PUBLIC.PRIMARY_KEY_3
2022-06-23 08:43:23 jdbc[3]: 
/**/prep947.setString(1, "FUN1");
2022-06-23 08:43:23 jdbc[3]: 
/**/prep947.setString(2, "localhost");
2022-06-23 08:43:23 jdbc[3]: 
/**/prep947.setString(3, null);
2022-06-23 08:43:23 jdbc[3]: 
/**/prep947.setObject(4, x);
2022-06-23 08:43:23 jdbc[3]: 
/**/prep947.setString(5, "informix");
2022-06-23 08:43:23 jdbc[3]: 
/**/prep947.setString(6, "47E8rRcSCgt12fTZ3b60sZrLVx911PoDS7YrFYHU43QiR3t/1A==");
2022-06-23 08:43:23 jdbc[3]: 
/**/prep947.setString(7, "informix");
2022-06-23 08:43:23 jdbc[3]: 
/**/prep947.setString(8, "z+owAPTcqQE7qx1sX5Ij2qDXiQl2QdNeEXTQJ0Pz61iPvb61FQ==");
2022-06-23 08:43:23 jdbc[3]: 
/**/prep947.setLong(9, 0L);
2022-06-23 08:43:23 jdbc[3]: 
/**/prep947.setBytes(10, org.h2.util.StringUtils.convertHexToBytes("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"));
2022-06-23 08:43:23 jdbc[3]: 
/**/prep947.setBytes(11, org.h2.util.StringUtils.convertHexToBytes("2100000004616c657274730005000000000464697361626c656400050000000000"));
2022-06-23 08:43:23 jdbc[3]: 
/**/prep947.setBytes(12, org.h2.util.StringUtils.convertHexToBytes("0500000000"));
2022-06-23 08:43:23 jdbc[3]: 
/**/prep947.setBytes(13, org.h2.util.StringUtils.convertHexToBytes("50000000127265706f7369746f72795365727665724964000100000000000000026461746162617365000600000068716d6f6e000a6167656e74436f6e6e656374696f6e50726f706572746965730000"));
2022-06-23 08:43:23 jdbc[3]: 
/**/prep947.setObject(14, x);
2022-06-23 08:43:23 jdbc[3]: 
/**/prep947.setObject(15, x);
2022-06-23 08:43:23 jdbc[3]: 
/**/prep947.executeUpdate();
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 3 shared write requesting for INFORMIX_SERVERS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 3 shared write ok INFORMIX_SERVERS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 jdbc[3]: 
/*SQL l:284 #:1 t:1*/update informix_servers set alias = ?, hostname = ?, service_name = ?, port = ?, monitor_user = ?, monitor_password = ?, admin_user = ?, admin_password = ?, group_id = ?, profile = ?, alerts = ?, properties = ?, agent_config = ?, password_secret_Key = ?, server_type = ? where id = 11 {1: 'FUN1', 2: 'localhost', 3: NULL, 4: 6090, 5: 'informix', 6: '47E8rRcSCgt12fTZ3b60sZrLVx911PoDS7YrFYHU43QiR3t/1A==', 7: 'informix', 8: 'z+owAPTcqQE7qx1sX5Ij2qDXiQl2QdNeEXTQJ0Pz61iPvb61FQ==', 9: CAST(0 AS BIGINT), 10: X'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', 11: X'2100000004616c657274730005000000000464697361626c656400050000000000', 12: X'0500000000', 13: X'50000000127265706f7369746f72795365727665724964000100000000000000026461746162617365000600000068716d6f6e000a6167656e74436f6e6e656374696f6e50726f706572746965730000', 14: CAST(X'aced00057372001f6a617661782e63727970746f2e737065632e5365637265744b6579537065635b470b66e230614d0200024c0009616c676f726974686d7400124c6a6176612f6c616e672f537472696e673b5b00036b65797400025b427870740003414553757200025b42acf317f8060854e0020000787000000010150d49c6152ac53bf23ea2daff16dbda' AS JAVA_OBJECT), 15: X'2b000000027365727665725479706500090000005374616e6461726400086973526561644f6e6c79000000'};
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 3 shared write unlock INFORMIX_SERVERS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 jdbc[3]: 
/**/prep947.close();
2022-06-23 08:43:23 jdbc[3]: 
/**/conn2679.close();
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 3 shared read unlock SYS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 database: disconnecting session #3
2022-06-23 08:43:23 database: closing /Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data/Projects/informixhq-server/server/h2db
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 2 shared read unlock SYS 
2022-06-23 08:43:23 lock: 1 shared read unlock SYS 
2022-06-23 08:43:24 database: closed
2022-06-23 08:43:24 database: disconnected session #3
2022-06-23 08:43:29 database: opening /Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data/Projects/informixhq-server/server/h2db (build 210)
2022-06-23 08:43:29 lock: 1 exclusive requesting for SYS 
2022-06-23 08:43:29 lock: 1 exclusive added for SYS 
2022-06-23 08:43:29 lock: 1 exclusive requesting for INFORMIX_SERVER_GROUPS 
2022-06-23 08:43:29 lock: 1 exclusive added for INFORMIX_SERVER_GROUPS 
2022-06-23 08:43:29 lock: 1 exclusive requesting for INFORMIX_SERVERS 
2022-06-23 08:43:29 lock: 1 exclusive added for INFORMIX_SERVERS 
2022-06-23 08:43:29 lock: 1 exclusive requesting for SYSTEM_REPORTS 
2022-06-23 08:43:29 lock: 1 exclusive added for SYSTEM_REPORTS 
2022-06-23 08:43:29 lock: 1 exclusive requesting for ALERTING_INCIDENTS 
2022-06-23 08:43:29 lock: 1 exclusive added for ALERTING_INCIDENTS 
2022-06-23 08:43:29 lock: 1 exclusive requesting for USERS 
2022-06-23 08:43:29 lock: 1 exclusive added for USERS 
2022-06-23 08:43:29 lock: 1 exclusive requesting for SENSOR_TYPES 
2022-06-23 08:43:29 lock: 1 exclusive added for SENSOR_TYPES 
2022-06-23 08:43:29 lock: 1 exclusive unlock SYS 
2022-06-23 08:43:29 lock: 1 exclusive unlock INFORMIX_SERVER_GROUPS 
2022-06-23 08:43:29 lock: 1 exclusive unlock INFORMIX_SERVERS 
2022-06-23 08:43:29 lock: 1 exclusive unlock SYSTEM_REPORTS 
2022-06-23 08:43:29 lock: 1 exclusive unlock ALERTING_INCIDENTS 
2022-06-23 08:43:29 lock: 1 exclusive unlock USERS 
2022-06-23 08:43:29 lock: 1 exclusive unlock SENSOR_TYPES 
2022-06-23 08:43:29 database: opened /Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data/Projects/informixhq-server/server/h2db
2022-06-23 08:43:29 database: connecting session #3 to /Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data/Projects/informixhq-server/server/h2db
2022-06-23 08:43:29 jdbc[3]: 
/*SQL */SET TRACE_LEVEL_FILE 3;
2022-06-23 08:43:29 jdbc[3]: 
/**/Connection conn2680 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:file:./h2db;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=3", "", "");
2022-06-23 08:43:29 jdbc[3]: 
/**/Statement stat1734 = conn2680.createStatement();
2022-06-23 08:43:29 jdbc[3]: 
/**/ResultSet rs1747 = stat1734.executeQuery("select a.id, a.when_created, a.state, b.meta, a.informix_server_id, c.alias from alerting_incidents a join alerting_criteria_violations b on a.id = b.alerting_incident_id, informix_servers c where a.informix_server_id = c.id and a.informix_server_id = 11 order by a.when_created desc ");
2022-06-23 08:43:29 jdbc[3]: exception
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "ALERTING_CRITERIA_VIOLATIONS" not found; SQL statement:
select a.id, a.when_created, a.state, b.meta, a.informix_server_id, c.alias from alerting_incidents a join alerting_criteria_violations b on a.id = b.alerting_incident_id, informix_servers c where a.informix_server_id = c.id and a.informix_server_id = 11 order by a.when_created desc  [42102-210]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:521)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:496)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:227)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:203)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8410)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8381)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:8370)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTablePrimary(Parser.java:1866)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableReference(Parser.java:2342)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableReference(Parser.java:2377)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectFromPart(Parser.java:2793)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:2900)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryPrimary(Parser.java:2783)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryTerm(Parser.java:2650)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpressionBody(Parser.java:2629)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpressionBodyAndEndOfQuery(Parser.java:2622)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpression(Parser.java:2615)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQuery(Parser.java:2576)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:707)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:674)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:644)
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:551)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:615)
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:553)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeQuery(JdbcStatement.java:92)
    at com.informix.hq.server.rest.api.alert.AlertingIncidentsResource.getIncidents(AlertingIncidentsResource.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor15.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$TypeOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:205)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:799)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:550)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1435)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:501)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1350)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.lambda$handle$1(HttpChannel.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:380)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:277)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:383)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:882)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1036)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2022-06-23 08:43:29 jdbc[3]: 
/**/stat1734.close();
2022-06-23 08:43:29 jdbc[3]: 
/**/conn2680.close();
```

As you can see there is no table with name "USER_ALERT_MESSENGERS"

Comment: H2 cannot drop non-temporary tables by itself. What is the real value of `BINARY_COLUMN_64K`? You can't define column as `meta 65536`, you need to specify the name of data type. `BINARY(65536)` is a fixed-with data type for values with exactly 65536 bytes, `BINARY VARYING(65536)` is a type for variable-width values. You also should use `BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY` instead of deprecated `IDENTITY`. Why commands aren't separated with semicolons?

Comment: Also H2 2.1.210 is outdated, current version in 2.1 series of releases is 2.1.214. But it isn't related to your problem.

Comment: real value is like below, have given you the sample. Regarding semicolons these are sample create statements which I have shared, in code there are semicolons.

"create table if not exists config(data binary(65536));"


Now I am not understanding why only these tables are dropping. For example, my code tries to run a select query and got the below error


ERROR h2database - h2db:jdbc[3] exception
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "ALERTING_CRITERIA_VIOLATIONS" not found; SQL statement:

Comment: Do you have any configuration options in JDBC URL such as `DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE`?

Comment: no, my JDBC URL only contanis trace level info "TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=3" like jdbc:h2:file:./h2db;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=3

Comment: I have the debug logs as well, if you want i can show you